# Where exactly are the instances being referenced by the variable?

Tags: swift, variables, reference, instance

```
var john1: Person1?
var unit4B : Apartment2?


john1 = Person1(name: "John")
unit4B = Apartment2(unit: "4B")
```

Where exactly are the instances? I know that `john1` and `unit4B` are the variables that reference the instances....however what exactly is the instance.....In the declaration above or in the initialization of the properties `name` and `unit`? And if the variables `john1` and `unit4B` are the instances then aren't they supposed to be referenced by a variable...? Im confused I don't know what I'm saying to be honest, I've read over the documentation about 5 times and still am confused! Is the property initialization itself an "instance" like `John` and `4B` that get initialized inside the properties `name` and `unit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *instances* are the individual "versions" of the objects that you're creating in memory. In this case, you're creating *two* instances here:

```
... = new Person1(name: "John")
... = new Apartment2(unit: "4B")
```

And you're *assigning* them to the variables you previously *defined*.

When you *defined* your variables here:

```
var john1: Person1?
var unit4B : Apartment2?
```

These are now *variables* that don't *refer* to anything. They don't "point to" any particular instance of an object. (But you *are* defining what types they can point to in the future.)

You can optionally combine the *definition* and *assignment* into a single statement like:

```
var john1: Person1? = Person1(name: "John")
var unit4B : Apartment2? = Apartment2(unit: "4B")
```